# How to use aws cloudwatch get-metric-widget-image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I would like to get Cloudwatch screenshot automatically since I have many instances.

But when I try to run get-metric-widget-image by aws cli command tool, I always get error.

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the GetMetricWidgetImage operation: MetricWidget property 'metricWidget' has a bad JSON content.

Is there anyone who could help me out? Thanks.

I could not find an example from aws doc. No exact example in below link.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/CloudWatch-Metric-Widget-Structure.html

My command is like this.

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-widget-image  --metric-widget "{ "width":600,"height":395,"metrics":[["AWS/EC2","CPUUtilization","InstanceId","i-01234567890123456",{"stat":"Average"}]],"period":300,"start":"-P30D","end":"PT0H","stacked":false,"yAxis":{"left":{"min":0.1,"max":1},"right":{"min":0}},"title":"CPU","annotations":{"horizontal":[{"color":"#ff6961","label":"Troublethresholdstart","fill":"above","value":0.5}], "vertical":[{"visible":true, "color":"#9467bd","label":"Bugfixdeployed","value":"2018-11-19T07:25:26Z","fill":"after"}]}}}" --output-format "png"
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The best way to get the correct json for your request is to use CloudWatch Console to construct the graph, then click on the `Source` tab, select `Image API` view and click `Copy Source` to copy the json generated there. You also need to wrap the json in single quotes, like this:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-widget-image --metric-widget \
'{
    "width": 600,
    "height": 395,
    "metrics": [
        [ "AWS/EC2", "CPUUtilization", "InstanceId", "i-01234567890123456", { "stat": "Average" } ]
    ],
    "period": 300,
    "stacked": false,
    "yAxis": {
        "left": {
            "min": 0.1,
            "max": 1
        },
        "right": {
            "min": 0
        }
    },
    "title": "CPU",
    "annotations": {
        "horizontal": [
            {
                "color": "#ff6961",
                "label": "Troublethresholdstart",
                "fill": "above",
                "value": 0.5
            }
        ],
        "vertical": [
            {
                "visible": true,
                "color": "#9467bd",
                "label": "Bugfixdeployed",
                "value": "2018-11-19T07:25:26Z",
                "fill": "after"
            }
        ]
    },
    "view": "timeSeries"
}'
```

Response to this will be a base64 encoded image, like this:

```
{
    "MetricWidgetImage": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAlgAAAGLEAYA..."
}
```

If you need the raw png image, you'll need to decode the response by doing something like this:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-widget-image --metric-widget 'JSON_GOES_HERE' | grep MetricWidgetImage | awk '{split($0,a,"\""); print a[4]}' | base64 --decode > graph.png
```

Comment: Thank you so much,Tartaglia! Very detailed answer. I am a green hand at AWS. It works for me and I could get the correct picture.

Comment: Even easier with JQ
Use `jq -r` for raw output (removes quotes from string); 
Assuming image request is in `request.json` file (can always inline it too); 

`aws cloudwatch get-metric-widget-image --metric-widget file://request.json --output-format png | jq -r '.MetricWidgetImage' | base64 --decode >| image.png`

Comment: jq is unneeded, and default format is always png (it's actually the only option right now). You can `aws cloudwatch get-metric-widget-image --metric-widget file://request.json --query 'MetricWidgetImage' --output text | base64 -d > image.png`

Comment: This post and answer are life / time savers! Any idea how to integrate this with Slack?

Comment: Also, @madeddie your script worked perfectly except that I required `... base64 -D ...` i.e. capital D not lowercase d

Comment: @Kwhitejr, right, that depends on your OS, linux uses -d, I think that might be a GNUism, MacOS allows for both lately, but some BSDs and older MacOS want capital -D.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a script I use to download images for the same metric for each day. The script shows how to invoke `aws cloudwatch get-metric-widget-image` with variable arguments and to convert output to a png file.

```
function getDbDailyMetricImage
{
    local date=$1
    local dbId=$2
    local metric=${3:-'CPUUtilization'}
    local metricMin=$4
    local metricMax=$5

    local dateF=$(date --date="$date" +%F)
    local start="${dateF}T00:00:00.000Z"
    local end="${dateF}T23:59:59.999Z"

    echo "Downloading image for $dbId $metric [$metricMin .. $metricMax]" \
         "and Time [$start .. $end]"
    aws --region us-east-1 cloudwatch get-metric-widget-image --metric-widget \
        '{
          "metrics": [
              [ "AWS/RDS", "'$metric'", "DBInstanceIdentifier", "'$dbId'", 
                { "period": 300, "yAxis": "left" } ]
          ],
          "yAxis": {
             "left": {
                 "min": '$metricMin',
                 "max": '$metricMax'
             }
          },
          "title": "'"$dateF $metric of $dbId vs Time UTC"'",
          "legend": {
             "position": "hidden"
          },
          "view": "timeSeries",
          "stacked": true,
          "period": 300,
          "width": 1200,
          "height": 800,
          "start": "'$start'",
          "end": "'$end'"
        }' \
        --output-format png --output text | base64 --decode > $metric-$dbId-$dateF.png
}

for daysAgo in {0..30}
do
    getDbDailyMetricImage $(date --date="$daysAgo days ago" +%F) mydb1 CPUUtilization 0 100
    getDbDailyMetricImage $(date --date="$daysAgo days ago" +%F) mydb1 ReadIOPS 0 10000
done
```

another useful analytic tool I use it to combine all or some of the graphs into one using ImageMagick convert -compose Multiply. For example,

```
convert ReadIOPS-mydb1-2019-0*.png -compose Multiply -layers flatten ReadIOPS-mydb1-2019-composite.png
```

Answer (score 3):

[JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) says that you've got one extra `}` at the end of your JSON.  Also, try wrapping the whole JSON block with single quotes `'` for easier differentiating and no need to escape the double quotes in the JSON string.

This should work for you:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-widget-image --metric-widget '{ "width":600,"height":395,"metrics":[["AWS/EC2","CPUUtilization","InstanceId","i-01234567890123456",{"stat":"Average"}]],"period":300,"start":"-P30D","end":"PT0H","stacked":false,"yAxis":{"left":{"min":0.1,"max":1},"right":{"min":0}},"title":"CPU","annotations":{"horizontal":[{"color":"#ff6961","label":"Troublethresholdstart","fill":"above","value":0.5}], "vertical":[{"visible":true, "color":"#9467bd","label":"Bugfixdeployed","value":"2018-11-19T07:25:26Z","fill":"after"}]}}' --output-format "png"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different answer. Within https://github.com/kcrossen/CloudWatch_Remote_Monitor/blob/master/Source_Code/ there is a Python script that will digest your dashboard source code mentioned by Tartaglia above and generate the proper json parameters for GetMetricWidgetImage. There's also a Kivy script to display the PNG images returned.