# Export screenshot of aws cloudwatch dasbhoard

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-cloudwatch

I created a cloudwatch dashboard to monitor CPU and other stats. Is there a way how I can export a screenshot of the dashboard from the console or by API call? Below is a sample dashboard made by manual screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! You can use the **GetMetricWidgetImage** API:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricWidgetImage.html

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/building-an-amazon-cloudwatch-dashboard-outside-of-the-aws-management-console/

The API can't graph a whole Dashboard in a single call, you need to call it for each widget (graph) on your dashboard. The API takes the exact same input as the the dashboard. On the CW Console, open a graph, click the "Source" tab and check the "Image API" checkbox and you'll have the exact input you need for the GetMetricWidgetImage API.

Comment: Thank you for that solution. Exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: For future readers, also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53388665/325742) which also has a snippet for converting the `MetricWidgetImage` from response into a  PNG image.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the raw png image, you'll need to decode the response by doing something like this:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-widget-image --metric-widget 'JSON_GOES_HERE' \
| grep MetricWidgetImage \
| awk '{split($0,a,"\""); print a[4]}' \
| base64 --decode > graph.png
```

Ref - https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/79079/how-to-use-aws-cloudwatch-get-metric-widget-image