# Using cloudwatch metric search in Aws Cli to find lambda durations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

In dashboards we often use the `graph search` functionality to catch all functions that have `part-of-function-name` in their function name.

```json
{
    "metrics": [
        [ { "expression": "SEARCH('{AWS/Lambda,FunctionName} part-of-function-name Duration', 'p90', 86400)", "id": "e1", "region": "eu-west-1" } ]
    ],
    "view": "bar",
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "stat": "Average",
    "period": 300
}
```

Can you use something similar in the aws cli? How? I was looking at the below command but don't know where to put it.

```sh
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name Duration \
--start-time 2014-04-08T23:18:00Z \
--end-time 2014-04-09T23:18:00Z \
--period 3600 --namespace AWS/Lambda --statistics p90
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as the API call [GetMetricStatistics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricStatistics.html) you can not use `SEARCH` in combination to get the metric statistics

Alternatively you can use [GetMetricWidgetImage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricWidgetImage.html)

> You can use the GetMetricWidgetImage API to retrieve a snapshot graph of one or more Amazon CloudWatch metrics as a bitmap image

[GetMetricWidgetImage: Metric Widget Structure and Syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/CloudWatch-Metric-Widget-Structure.html)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53388665/2246345) is a working example of the call using aws cli.